# Trackpad stops working late at night

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, magic-trackpad

May sound silly, but for the past few weeks, if I'm on my Macbook Pro (mid-2012) late at night (say, post-1 a.m.) - and I often am! - my trackpad will stop working. I can't move the cursor or click, etc. But I can grab the mouse and it works just fine.

I thought it had something to do with heating up too much or the laptop not being restarted in along time. I've remedied both of those issues numerous times and it doesn't matter whether I just restarted it or not, it simply won't work. Then, sometime in the early morning hours, it decides it's back and I don't have a problem with it all day.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Don't know about this, but the same thing happens if you try to click (or use force touch) when  is shut down.

Comment: It's Apple telling you you need some sleep !! :)   Sorry - couldn't resist...

Comment: My first question would be: *Have you got any sort of scheduled activity that runs in the early morning?*

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, and I’ve told it a hundred times, I control it, it doesn’t control me.... at least until the Singularity. But I’m my own man ‘til then!

Comment: @Monomeeth Okay, my answer is “I think so” (I know, for example, the app Cocktail runs daily and weekly scripts); how might one determine whether and how many scheduled activities one has? (Asking for a friend).